# PHP. Строковое выражение в число

Tags: php

```
$str = "3 * 5";
$num = (int)$str;
echo $num  //выводит 3, а надо 15
```

Как преобразовать строку в число, чтобы сразу показался результат арифметического умножения?

Comment: [Преобразование строк в числа](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) вроде все детально описано. Для того, чтобы вывело `15` нужно писать так `$str = 3 * " 5";` или так: `$str = "3" * "5";`

Answer (score 5):

```
$num = eval($str);
```

вычислит вам искомое выражение, однако следует понимать, что функция [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php) выполнит вообще любой код, а не только математические формулы. Поэтому можно дополнительно валидировать строку  на содержание цифр, точек и знаков математических операций, в т.ч. скобок.

Либо искать сторонние решения, которые будут заниматься парсингом выражения и вычислять его в соответствие с принятыми правилами приоритета операций.

Comment: Добавьте пару строк о том, что произошло при приведении типа.

Comment: @Other в комментариях уже скинули ссылку на порядок приведения строки  к числу. имеет ли смысл добавлять это?

Comment: Скинули уже после моего коммента. Добавлять или нет - Ваше право. Комментарий - не ответ, де-юре.

Comment: @Other я просто думаю, что автор и так понимает, что это строка и сама по себе она не вычислится. Так что почему там выводится 3 вряд ли является загадкой.